# How to write conditional expression in LaTeX with text and math

Tags: math-mode, equations, cases, logic

Being new in LaTeX I don't know where to look for the proper resources.
I know this is probably documented for easily somewhere out there, but I'm struggling with knowing where to look - any help isappreciated.

How would you reproduce in LaTeX this conditional expression with one curly brace on the left side?

[image: This is what I'm trying to reproduce]

Comment: Hi @Iver, as a new user I recommend you reading some tips on [how to ask a good question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). There is more probability that you receive good answers and that your post will be useful for future users. Also try adding a [mwe](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) to your question.

Comment: @GiuTeX Thanks, will do!

Comment: You are welcome, and welcome also to the community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  t(v) =
  \begin{cases}
    \text{John} & \text{hvis $v$ er variabelen $x$}\\
    \text{Paul} & \text{hvis $v$ er variabelen $y$}\\
    \text{George} & \text{hvis $v$ er variabelen $z$}\\
    \text{Yoko} & \text{ellers}
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Jendrik notes in the comments that the `cases*` environment, available with `mathtools`, sets the right-hand alignment automatically as text, rather than math, which is useful in this situation.  Thus, the `cases*` equivalent of the above code would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  t(v) =
  \begin{cases*}
    \text{John} & hvis $v$ er variabelen $x$\\
    \text{Paul} & hvis $v$ er variabelen $y$\\
    \text{George} & hvis $v$ er variabelen $z$\\
    \text{Yoko} & ellers
  \end{cases*}
\]
\end{document}
```

Here's an alternative with `tabstackengine`, allowing the content to be set in text mode directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
  \setstackgap{L}{1.1\normalbaselineskip}% ROW BASELINESKIP
  \setstacktabbedgap{1em}% INTER-COLUMN GAP
  t(v) = \left\{
    \tabbedCenterstack[l]{% LEFT ALIGNED STACK CONTENT
    John & hvis $v$ er variabelen $x$\\
    Paul & hvis $v$ er variabelen $y$\\
    George & hvis $v$ er variabelen $z$\\
    Yoko & ellers
    }
  \right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you!

Comment: I’d suggest using `mathtools` instead of `amsmath` (which is then loaded internally by `mathtools`), and then use `cases*` instead of `cases`. In this way, one doesn’t need to use`\text{}` in the second column.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner Thanks for the tip.  I have added it to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution with just `array` and `bigdelim`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigdelim, array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \sffamily
\begin{tabular}{l@{\,}l@{\quad}l}
  \ldelim\{{4}{*}[$t(v)={}$]
 & John & hvis $v$ er variabelen $x$ \\
 & Paul & hvis $v$ er variabelen $y$ \\
 & George & hvis $v$ er variabelen $z$ \\
 & Yoko & ellers
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Steven has already said enough, but just for completeness and for proving that LaTeX offers always new roads I'll post another solution by means of .., though I think `cases` environment is the most appropriate for this job.

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \[
        t(v) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
           \text{John} & \text{hvis $v$ er variabelen $x$}\\
           \text{Paul} & \text{hvis $v$ er variabelen $y$}\\
           \text{George} & \text{hvis $v$ er variabelen $z$}\\
           \text{Yoko} & \text{ellers}
        \end{array}\right.
    \]
\end{document}
```

This produces

[image: With array]

Notice that `amsmath` package is only needed for `text command`. A benefit from using `array` would be that you can control alignment by means of `r` and `l` (respectively right aligned, and left aligned) arguments in `\begin{array}{lr}`, and you can add lines as well as control manually spacing, by writing

```
\[
    t(v) = \left\{\begin{array}{l@{\hspace{3em}}|r}
        \text{John} & \text{hvis $v$ er variabelen $x$}\\
        \hline
        \text{Paul} & \text{hvis $v$ er variabelen $y$}\\
        \text{George} & \text{hvis $v$ er variabelen $z$}\\
        \text{Yoko} & \text{ellers}
    \end{array}\right.
\]
```

`@{\hspace{3em}}` can be set to whichever value in `em`, `cm`, `pt` and other measure you like for making custom space between columns, while `|` can be used for adding vertical lines bewreen the arry columns. Finally adding `\hline` you can achieve horizontal rules.

Little addendum: `\left\{` and `\right.` fake the case behaviour of `cases` environment, so that if you prefer you can switch it to othe parenthesis, as `[`, `(`, `\langle` and so on.